# Enhance CTA base on Feature

Tags: cta

I have a CTA on a card with the behavior of opening a modal with 2 tabs called "Feature #1" and "Feature #2". The system is flexible and users can configure to show only "Feature #1", "Feature #2" or both of them.

How can a user know which feature the CTA will show when interacting with?

Any suggestions?
T4R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Card, you can use **Checkboxes** to allow the user to select the features of his choice to display. If he wants he can select either one feature or both, and the name of the CTA can be "show, submit", also the CTA name may vary based on the requirements.

Comment: Yeah, sure, I have done it. I think that better solution for this time. Dynamic text on the CTA. 3 text content base on 3 cases :D

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I understood correctly, but you can also change the text in the button. Instead of *Save* *Submit* or *Confirm*, you can use words like *Preview* *Choose filters* *Configure* to indicate there are following steps after clicking the button.
Another way is to put "Continue" and below the button just a small (11-13px  font size) one sentence of explanation "Configure your features" or "Choose which features you want to show".

Again, not sure if that answers your question but feel free to dig deeper I am happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have a CTA that can open multiple variations of content, based on a settings configuration, and you want to clarify the final behavior of that CTA.

There are a few things you need to consider:

- What is the purpose of changing the features? Does the change matter for the final user who will click the CTA? Are the changes significant enough to be worth a differentiation? If the answer is no, then the CTA can remain as it is.
- Will the context of the CTA indicate which features are possible? If the context is clear enough, then the CTA can remain the same.
- How much design flexibility do you have? Can you use multiple buttons or styles? Can you change the layout of the card or the position of the buttons?

Based on that, some solutions would be:

1. Change the label of the CTA to mention which feature will be triggered.
2. Change some visual aspects of the CTA (icon, color, size, radius etc.) based on the feature that will be triggered.
3. Improve the context (the card) in which the CTA appears so that it will indicate which features are possible, and thus shift the focus from the CTA to the card.
4. Change the position of the CTA inside the card based on the feature that will be triggered.